# Looking definition of \setminus to call with \DeclareMathSymbol

Tags: symbols

I'm using `Mnsymbol` package but I don't like how looks `\setminus`. Because that I want use the default `\setminux` making

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\DeclareSymbolFont{Symbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Setminus}{\mathbin}{Symbols}{}

\usepackage{Mnsymbol}
\begin{document}
$\setminus$ $\Setminus$
\end{document}
```

but, as you can see, I miss something. How I get that?

Comment: Oh well, I thought that making \Setminus (note the S) not cause problems.

Comment: Yes, is right. I just want call the default `\setminus` with another command. But I miss something ...

Comment: Look my MWE :v .... the last `{}`

Comment: I add a `documentclass`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764)

Comment: @Werner yes ... my English isn't so good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `\setminus` and the setups for the `symbols` math font can be found in `fontmath.ltx`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\DeclareSymbolFont{Symbols}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{Symbols}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Setminus}{\mathbin}{Symbols}{"6E}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
$\setminus$ $\Setminus$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Package `MnSymbol` (with uppercase `S`)  redefines the standard `symbols` font of LaTeX, thus it needs a different name (`Symbols`) to avoid a conflict.

Comment: Really thanks, I will consider your suggestion. Why you make `\SetSymbolFont{Symbols}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}`?

Comment: @juanuni Completeness.

Comment: And if I use another symbols like `AMSa`, I just write `AMSa` instead `Symbols` in `\SetSymbolFont` order?

Comment: @juanuni And you might need additional font declarations. In this case the font was already declared and defined. The slot number can usually be found by looking into the definition of the another symbol.